# R - change of boxplot on bwplot from lattice

Tags: r, boxplot, lattice, bwplot

I was tasked to change the code which uses graphics package into something with `bwplot` from `lattice` package with the same result.

Boxplot:

```
par(mai = c(1, 1, 1, 1), omi = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
set.seed(591)
xx1 <- rnorm(20, mean = 3, sd = 3.6)
xx2 <- rpois(40, lambda = 3.5)
xx3 <- rchisq(31, df = 5, ncp = 0)
box1 <- boxplot(xx1, xx2, xx3, names = c("Group-1", "Group-2", "Group-3"), cex = 0.7)
```

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to change it, I can't insert these 3 plots in 1 chart.
All I have done so far:

```
library(lattice)
bwplot(xx1,ylab="Group-1")
bwplot(xx2,ylab="Group-2")
bwplot(xx3,ylab="Group-3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code to do it using `lattice` package

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(xx1, levels ="Group-1")
df2 <- data.frame(xx2, levels ="Group-2")
df3 <- data.frame(xx3, levels ="Group-3")
colnames(df1) <- c("Data","Group")
colnames(df2) <- c("Data","Group")
colnames(df3) <- c("Data","Group")

df <- bind_rows(df1,df2,df3)

bwplot(Data~Group,df)
```

[image]